# Xamarin forms Label new line

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Label` in my Xamarin forms page, that receives it's `Text` from it's view model, and the text contains the `\n` character.
How can I make the `Label` to automatically split the text into two different rows?

Comment: It should automatically split into two lines.

Comment: Of course it should, but unfortunately it doesn't.
Please note that the text is received from a resource file, it is not part of the XAML.

Comment: Does it happen on iOS/Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Copied from [a thread in Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29700/label-and-n)*

Probably your code:

```
<Label FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Gray" Text="{translation:TranslationResource MyExpertsView_NoExpertsText}"  IsVisible="{Binding IsNoExpertsFound}"></Label>
```

---

Since your text is retrieved from a resource file, the `Text` property of `Label` treats the input as plain text and will not allow any escape characters.

You may consider pre-processing the strings (replacing all \n to line feeds) from the`TranslationResource`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Only changing the text in the code dynamically did the work.

Answer (score 55):

Very simple add following unicode instead of \n

```
 &#10;
```

**for ex:**

```
Text="General &#10; Studies - I"
```

Answer (score 12):

One way to solve it would be replacing in your VM the '\n' with `System.Environment.NewLine`

`string Text = "Text first line\nText second line".Replace("\n", System.Environment.NewLine);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56981145/4230687

Comment: This is the best solution imo, it will work more reliably across different devices whereas using the unicode approach did not work when tested on a samsung tablet.

Comment: In c#, I use string Text = String.Format("first line{0}second line", System.Environment.NewLine);

Answer (score 7):

You can do that it like that:

```
Text = "First line string&#x0a;Second line string"
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is use "Shift+Enter" to add new line in your resource

Comment: This is how I always do it! :D

Answer (score 1):

To changed it on ViewModel, you can use this method. It'll update all \n on your string as string.Replace just change the first occurance.

```
    // Replace \n to Environtment.NewLine
    public string StringUpdateNewLineFormat(string sentences)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(sentences, @"^""|""$|\\n?", System.Environment.NewLine);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use `\n`, i'm using XAML and I'm binding the text through `Binding` on the label.