# Bind breakline symbol to Label.Text

Tags: string, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When binding a Label.Text
have tried many ways:
\n \r 
  
 
but none of them are being displayed as breakline
I refuse to believe I will need to dynamically create a Custom control to generate spans on numbers of breakline symbol...
is there any easier/simpler approach ?

What I've tried:

- string BreaklineText = "Text first line\nText second line"
- string BreaklineText = "Text first line\rText second line"
- string BreaklineText = @"Text first line `&#x0a;` Text second line"
- string BreaklineText = @"Text first line`&#10;`Text second line"

The xaml:
`<Label Text="{Binding BreaklineText}"/>`

It should be displayed on my view as
Text first line
Text second line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin forms Label new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927167/xamarin-forms-label-new-line)

Comment: the answers on this thread does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the optimal solution since I wanted to find a symbol that could be interpreted as BreakLine on XAML, but it will do the job.

`string BreaklineText = "Text first line\nText second line".Replace("\n", System.Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 0):

using Ascii equivalent `&#10;` in XAML should work, you have missed `;`

```
<Label Text="Text first line&#10;Text second line"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not exactly the solution, the string is being binded from my VM as ```public string BreakLineText = "Text first line&#10;Text second line"``` and it won't be displayed as it should

Comment: note that I am using bindings in xaml ```Label Text="{Binding BreaklineText}"```

Comment: why are you using `@` just use \n in the code behind

Comment: removing it also will not work...
hope the question is clear.
It's actually pretty straight forward, imagine the string is "First line\nSecond line" binding this to my XAML the '\n' won't be displayed as a BreakLine

Comment: is it on android or iPhone?

Comment: both , don't think it has something to do with the device itself.

Comment: it does matter. \n and \r\n are different in different OS environments

Comment: anyway, it does not answer the question.
I've posted a "solution" which is not the optimal since I was expecting any symbol that my XAML could interpreted as a break line, \n and \r\n are not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I built on @Motumbo and set System.Environment.NewLine to a variable like

`var nl = System.Environment.NewLine;`

then I could write variations on:

`string text = "some text" + nl + "text on newline";`

Also found that "\r\n" works on Droid and UWP. Did not have iOS to test. So:

`string text = "some text\r\ntext on newline";`

worked for me.