# Xamarin Forms : Display multiple lines of text in grid cell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display label text in multi-line format, as-

```
First Name
Last Name
Date of birth
```

All this should appear in single cell of the grid.

This is what I have tried:

```
 string full_details = firstname + lastname + dob;
 Label name = new Label
 {
   Text = full_details,
   MaxLines = 3,
   LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
 };
 grid.Children.Add(name,0,0);
```

Comment: Did you already try something - if yes, please add the code

Comment: Have you tried using `Span` for `Label` ?

Comment: You can use `\n`Here is a similar thread Or you can use `Environment.NewLine` in the C# code. eg: `string full_details = "firstname" + Environment.NewLine + " lastname ";`. you can refer to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927167/xamarin-forms-label-new-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
string full_details = firstname + "\n" + lastname + "\n" + dob;
Label name = new Label
{
   Text = full_details,
   MaxLines = 3,
   LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
grid.Children.Add(name,0,0);
```

Try adding line breaker.

For different font try doing something like this,

```
    var formattedString = new FormattedString ();
    formattedString.Spans.Add (new Span{ Text = firstname , ForegroundColor = Color.Red, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold });

    var span = new Span { Text = "\n" + lastname };
    formattedString.Spans.Add(span);
    formattedString.Spans.Add (new Span { Text = "\n" +dob, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic, FontSize =  Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) });

    Label name = new Label 
    {
        FormattedString = formattedString
    };
```

Comment: yes this works but what if I want to add different font layouts to each line?

Comment: your firstname, lastname & dob are local variables or Binding variables for placeholders in xaml?

Comment: They are local variables

Answer (score 1):

try this code snippets, may help

```
<Label x:Name="MovAvgLabel" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding Path=MovingAverage}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Span Text="&#10;Moving Average&#10;Today"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```